# Populate combobox with data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, dataset, xampp

I'm trying to populate my combobox with data from a table in mysql, here is my code, I can't see what the issue is. My combobox doesn't return any data, it is just blank.

```
    Private Sub cbxCompanyName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxCompanyName.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim constr As String = "Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password="
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = constr
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dim StrSql As String = "SELECT Company Name FROM client_details"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(StrSql, objconnection)
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Client_details")

    da.Fill(dt)


    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        cbxCompanyName.DataSource = dt
        cbxCompanyName.DisplayMember = "Company Name" 'What is displayed

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```vb
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    cbxCompanyName.DataSource = dt
    cbxCompanyName.DisplayMember = "Company Name"
    cbxCompanyName.ValueMember = "Company Name"

End If
```

Comment: thanks, I added that but I think it was also a case of i was not loading the combobox as the form was loading.

Comment: It's a bit odd that you do this in `cbxCompanyName.SelectedIndexChanged` event, maybe you should move the code to `Form.Load` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..!

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

```
    cbxCompanyName.DataSource = dt
    **cbxCompanyName.DataBind();**

End If
```

Comment: Hi, I get error 'databind' is not a member of system.windows.form.combobox

Comment: use data reader to execute your sql command then add this code instead  of 'If' Part.

cbxCompanyName.items.add(readername[0]);

Answer (score 0):

You sql command text is wrong. When you have spaces in the column names or table names you should enclose the name in a special character that delimits the start and the end of the column name.

```
Dim StrSql As String = "SELECT `Company Name` FROM client_details"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(StrSql, objconnection)
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable("Client_details")
```

For MySql this special character is the backtick (keep pressed <kbd>ALT</kbd> and press <kbd>096</kbd> on the numeric keyboard).

Of course it would be much better to avoid these spaces at all.
If it is not too late I suggest to change that column name removing the space

Comment: I did this aswell before you suggested, the only problem I had was I couldn't manually change the column names in the datagrid view even after using `frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Company Name"`

Comment: Did you mean `frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Company Name"` ?

Comment: That was what I had before it had no effect on the column name, is it supposed to be where I bind my dataset?

Comment: I don't understand, we are binding the datatable to a combobox, not to  a datagridview. Can you explain?

Comment: You in the first answer told me to not have spaces in my column names, which I changed. The only reason I had spaces was because I couldn't manually change the column names in my datagrid. I used the code in the second response you gave me but it had no effect, could you tell me where exactly to place it?

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub cbxCompanyName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxCompanyName.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim constr As String = "Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password="
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = constr
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

```
Dim StrSql As String = "SELECT Company Name FROM client_details"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(StrSql, objconnection)
```

Dim dr As OleDbDataReader=cmd.ExecuteReader

```
 While dr.Read
     cbxCompanyName.items.add(dr.item(0))
 End While
 dr.close()
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is correct when placing into a combobox, but one thing is omitted. In order to immediately access that list the starting index must be set for the selected items, or you will return the contents of 'System.Data.DataRowView' when ever you go to collect the contents of ComboBox1.Text.

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd
ds = New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(ds, Table)
ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "imgURL"
conn.Close()
da.Dispose()
conn.Dispose()
ComboBox1.SelectionStart = 0 'This is what is missing from above.
Dim current_imgURL As String = "http://10.1.1.10/photos/" & ComboBox1.Text
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New WebClient().DownloadData(current_imgURL)))
```

This example loads a combobox with image file names and pulls them from a server location. I wanted to preload the first image from the combobox right after I filled it from a MySql and ran into this issue because the index for selection is triggered only when the user clicks the combobox, not when data is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code i hope that it should work

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("connection string")
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tableName", con)
Dim dt As New DataTable

da.Fill(dt)
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "fieldName to show in ComboBox"enter code here
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "fieldName to show in textbox")
```